# Automatically label line numbers in minted enviornment

Tags: listings, minted, code, fancyvrb

I've recently swapped from the `listing` package to the `minted` package for my code listings. When I used lstlistings, I was able to redefine `\lst@Key` to automatically place labels of the format `\lst@label:\arabic{lstnumber}` at every line number.

After skimming through the `minted` and `fancyvrb` source I have not been able to find a way to do this for the `minted` package however.

Redefining `\theFancyVerbLine` seems like the obvious solution, but i don't have access to the minted label there.

Any ideas for how this might be implemented?

Comment: What's the rationale about adding “automatic labels”? You need to check the line number anyway, don't you?

Comment: @egreg It's just for hyperref's. It's nice to be able to jump straight to the line being referenced.

Comment: There is a deleted answer which pretty much does that https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122906/36296

Comment: I don't see it; is there any way to view deleted answers? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6ZH5.png (the line cut off reads `\def\theFancyVerbLine{\rmfamily\tiny\arabic{FancyVerbLine}\label{minted:line:\the\value{mintedcount}:\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
`)

Comment: @candr Please don't add your solution into your question. You could write a self-answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot - that was exaclty the pointer i needed! As you can see in the edit, I ended up wrapping minted in a new enviornment so i could access the label of individual listings instead of just a global minted counter. This also makes hyperlinks jump to the exact line, instead of all going to where mintedcount was last refstepped.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh i didnt know you could do that. I've moved my solution to an answer now (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up wrapping `minted` in a new environment, allowing me to make `\theFancyVerbLine` place labels with the `<label> : <linenum>` format, which jump to the exact line.

```latex
\newcounter{lstlinenum}
\newenvironment{lst}[4][]
{
    \setcounter{lstlinenum}{0}
    \def\theFancyVerbLine{
        \rmfamily\tiny\arabic{FancyVerbLine}
        \refstepcounter{lstlinenum}
        \label{#4:\arabic{lstlinenum}}
    }
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{listing}[htp]
    \caption{#3}\label{#4}
    \begin{minted}[#1]{#2}%
}{
    \end{minted}
    \end{listing}
    \def\theFancyVerbLine{\rmfamily\tiny\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}%
}
```